# get elements produced by a dom-repeat template selected by a content element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer

i'm trying to get elements produced by a helper elements on polymer, which is selected of a content tag.
this a simple example that I trying to do:

dom-module

```html
<dom-module id="x-foo">
<template>
    <content id="content"></content>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
     attached: function()
            var effectiveChildren = this.getEffectiveChildren("span");
            console.log(effectiveChildren);
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

index.html

```html
<template is="dom-bind">
    <x-foo>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </template>
    </x-foo>
</template>
<script>
    var scope = document.querySelector("template[is='dom-bind']");
    scope.list = [{"name":"javier"},{"name":"pedro"},{"name":"javier2"}]
</script>
```

--- edit ---

I try with:

```
getDistributedNodes()
getEffectiveChildren()
getContentChildren()
```

any hint??

Comment: Have you tried `Polymer.dom(this).getEffectiveChildren("span");` instead?

Comment: Polymer.dom(this).getEffectiveChildren("span");
is not a function, but Polymer.dom(this).getEffectiveChildren;
return a empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there was a little bit more to this, but also a little bit less.  The code you looking for is:

```
this.queryAllEffectiveChildren('span');
```

However, there's gonna be a lot of particularities around when all of the DOM is available to actually run this depending on the final application of your component. I've got it working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/nfER4vTe5y7CddHYO5bk?p=preview the main thing being I'm waiting for the `dom-change` event on the `dom-repeat` to check for those elements. There's definitely something cleaner to be used around DOM flush or the like, but I'm not sure which way to direct you in there.  The main crux is:

```
<template>
  There are {{childCount}} children.<br/>
    <content></content>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',
        listeners: {
          'dom-change': 'childCheck'
        },
          childCheck: function() {
              this.childCount = this.queryAllEffectiveChildren('span').length;
              console.log(this.queryAllEffectiveChildren('span'));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: with 
`var insertionPoint = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('content');
var distributed = Polymer.dom(insertionPoint).getDistributedNodes();`

distributed I get a Array with length 3:
[text, template, text]
I just looking for a element produced by the template